# Looking for identification of SF story where humans are the "ancient evil"

Tags: story-identification

Unique short SF story where aliens being invaded by other aliens, went looking for allies (to help save their galactic empire).

While being chased by the antagonistic aliens, they encountered a barrier surrounding a solar system. They somehow managed to disable it and found a solar system where the third planet from the Sun showed signs of life. When they landed, they were received by a human girl who greeted them. The enemy ship which followed them also landed, but were destroyed by the humans easily.

Upon learning of the aliens request, the humans decided to help the aliens, and moved their entire world to follow the aliens' ship. Too late the aliens realized that these humans were the ancient war mongering race which was sealed up eons ago and they had accidentally released them.

Could someone please help to identify this title for me. Thanks.

Comment: sounds like an awesome story... I want to know what its called too!

Comment: Aargh, I have this story, but can't remember where. A couple of clarifications: the aliens were looking specifically for the semi-mythical Terrans, who had almost conquered the whole galaxy thousands of years before, as the last hope against the new threat. And they didn't release them accidentally, but as part of the deal once they agreed to help. Closing lines: "I see they're bringing their moon with them..."

Comment: And one more thing, in case it triggers anyone's memory: when the aliens land and first approach a human, they try to talk in Terran and the human responds with "Me Tarzan, you Jane", then switches to Galactic and says "Skip it, ancient witticism."

Comment: @Jonathan Miller: Yup, it is awesome @ Daniel Roseman: YES! Thank you. I was about to lose hope and think that no one else has read this text. I posted it on several boards but to no avail. It seems your memory is clearer than mine. Although my description (which is wrong) differs a bit from yours, the story is easy to remember because it is unique. You don't find humans in Sci-fi being so badass. Usually they are the struggling race trying to "explore new worlds blah blah blah". I was hoping to find the title and see if there is any follow up to the story =\. Or just reread for a good romp.

Answer (score 27):

Based on the comments by Daniel Roseman, it seems to be "With Friends Like These" by Alan Dean Foster.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I dug and found the synopsis:
"With Friends Like These" (1971) The Yops, who prey on all other species for food, have driven the remaining strength of the united galaxy to violate the Edict forbidding contact with the most feared race in known space, left trapped on their own planet for centuries: the humans of Earth.
I'll be going to down to the local library tomorrow for confirmation but I highly think that is the book. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is the one I was thinking of, certainly.