# Sci-Fi short story about Galaxy alliance coming to free earth to help fight a war

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for title and author of a story where earth was trapped behind an energy field because humans were the greatest enemy. Years later, the alliance comes to free earth to help in a war and Humanity is living a seemingly bucolic existence but that is due to extreme tech advancement and when the shield is removed, humanity takes the entire earth with them to go fight. The aliens who released earth say " I almost feel sorry for our enemies"

Comment: This feels so familiar. Hope an answer comes up soon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for identification of SF story where humans are the "ancient evil"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/looking-for-identification-of-sf-story-where-humans-are-the-ancient-evil)

Comment: And also of [Short story where the Earth has been kept inside a force field for millennia](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58353/4495).

Comment: We don't close story-ID questions as dupes unless confirmed as such by the asker

Answer (score 6):

*With Friends Like These*, by Alan Dean Foster.

Comment: I feel like I should be asking you to justify your answer, but frankly, all of it is in the two "duplicate" questions mentioned above.