# Story about Galactic authorities confining humanity to the solar system

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story I once read, in which Humanity sends out a space ship to try leaving the Solar System, and it is promptly destroyed by a military ship belonging to the Galactic Empire, which then broadcasts an announcement declaring that the ship was destroyed for the crime of attempting to leave, which is a violation of the treaty permanently restricting humanity to their own solar system.

Humanity won't stand for a complete alien stranger to say "you agreed to stay home forever", goes on war footing, manages to conquer the galactic government. In the end, documentation is found showing that yes, many millennia ago there had been a war, which ended with Humanity agreeing to be permanently confined to Earth.

Comment: Not your name...but is it your final form?

Comment: Sounds similar to "With Friends Like These" (see [Looking for identification of SF story where humans are the “ancient evil”](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/19014/31936)) but some of the details don't match up.

Comment: It's not "With Friends Like These", although that's also a good story.

Comment: The first part reminds me a little of "All the Way Back" by Michael Shaara, although the second part is not a match at all.

Comment: @user14111 I think it was a novel. I don't remember. It was a long time ago.

Comment: @Megha ["All the way back"](http://hell.pl/szymon/Baen/The%20best%20of%20Jim%20Baens%20Universe/The%20World%20Turned%20Upside%20Down/0743498747__13.htm) is also a good short story. In the story I'm looking for, the initial ship that is destroyed is destroyed within our own solar system, and the destroying ship is not _polite_ about it like the ones in All The Way Back.

Comment: @Thisisn'tmyrealname - yeah, that's why it was a comment not an attempt at an answer - it just reminded me a little.  I hope you find the story, though, it sounds interesting.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the plot of the classic videogame [Homeworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeworld#Plot). Did you read this story in a book or on internet? It could be a transcript of the game if the latest.

Comment: According to the plot of "Homeworld", the protagonist group _who knew they weren't native to the world they lived on_ found a buried spaceship with a map leading back to home. The story I'm looking for had a _Humanity_, living _on earth_, developing spaceflight for what they thought was the first time. So this Homeworld story looks like it's an OK story on its own, but it doesn't look like the one I want. Thank you.

Comment: Did you know how long ago this was written, or how long ago you read it?

Comment: How long ago it was written? No clue. How long ago did I read it? At least two and a half decades, probably closer to three.

Comment: I remember reading at least the first novel in a series:  A young man (YM forward) runs away from his home - he is growing breasts.  The sword trainer cuts them off/burns him.  His family is genetically gifted/altered as their forebears did dna stuff - legends of them on this planet (which all factions know they have been exiled to - might be earth and resources limited and hidden) is that in battle, their family could get injured and heal and get back into battle.

Comment: *That's* why you *never* lay down specific rules for eternity. You *always* include some "reevaluation" interval to ensure the rules are still appropriate for the current situation. Heeding that good practice might have saved that Galactic Empire some ammo ;)

Comment: Somewhat similar to Michael Freeport's "A Faded Star" series, but with some exceptions. Do recommend read even in case of not a match, so not posting anything more to avoid spoilers.

Answer (score -4):

Sounds like ***[The Forever War](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21611.The_Forever_War)*** (1974) by Joe Haldeman.

In this story, the ships would mysteriously lose some atmosphere and fuel so they were "nicely turned back" by these master beings.

From Goodreads:

> The Earth's leaders have drawn a line in the interstellar sand—despite the fact that the fierce alien enemy that they would oppose is inscrutable, unconquerable, and very far away. A reluctant conscript drafted into an elite Military unit, Private William Mandella has been propelled through space and time to fight in the distant thousand-year conflict; to perform his duties without rancor and even rise up through military ranks. Pvt. Mandella is willing to do whatever it takes to survive the ordeal and return home. But "home" may be even more terrifying than battle, because, thanks to the time dilation caused by space travel, Mandella is aging months while the Earth he left behind is aging centuries.

Comment: KINDA LIKE  The Forever war & VERY much like Haldemon's style!

Comment: But in *The Forever War* the war was galactic in scope; humanity wasn't restricted to the solar system.

Comment: This doesn't match the description in the question very well

Comment: This isn't it, but thank you for trying